# Unable to change display name on OAuth consent screen

Tags: google-api, verification

I have developed an app that synchronises our users' Google contacts with the School's database. When I submitted the consent screen for verification I was asked to change the display name, as it violated branding policies by including GMail in the title. However when I try to update the consent screen in the API Console, after changing the app name the Save button remains greyed out, so I can't change it. How do proceed now?

Note the app is currently in use with an unverified consent screen, but new users are now unable to sign up since Google appear to have tightened their policies.

Also the app is only used by members of our organisation, so it should really be an internal app. However the Make Internal link is deactivated, apparently because I am not a G Suite User. However we have a G Suite for Education account, so does this not make me a G Suite user?

Comment: Hi John, as I understand, you have used a gmail account to verify the app, but as far as I know you should use a gsuite account, which is always in your domain, not in gmail.com domain, and preferably an admin account, to verify apps in a domain. Have you tried to access the consent options through a gsuite admin account?

Comment: I AM using a G Suite account to log in to the API Console. It's an admin account in the School's domain, not in gmail.com, which I use to administer our G Suite for Education package.

Answer (score 0):

As no-one has provided a solution it looks like there is none. Therefore I’ve resorted to my plan B, which is to create a new API Project and consent screen, This time I created it as an internal project, which avoids any complications of validation. The previous project was created public as it was envisaged that parents with private Gmail accounts might also use it. However with the constraints of GDPR it has been decided to restrict it to employees only. Fortunately I have found a way for existing users to continue using the old version, while new users have to register using the new consent screen.

It appears that the message about not being able to change to a local project if you’re not a G Suite user is a red herring. I suspect you just can’t change project type once it’s in use, because of the possible implications for existing users,